# RedirectToAction not working in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Following is one Login function in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogIn(string email, string password)
{          
   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");           
}
```

This calls Index function of HomeController but same screen i.e Login screen remains on browser. The following are the routes in my MVC application:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
}
```

I am not sure what is the issue. I search net for this but there is deviance in the issue faced by other users.

**Update**

HomeController :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your HomeController?

Comment: Could you inspect the requests using Fiddler or a developer bar on the browser? I suspect that there's a filter on the other controller sending you back to login because you're not logged in yet

Comment: Does you index action on Home Controller have `[AllowAnonymous]`

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: Use a tool like Fiddler, or Chrome Dev Tools, and have a look at what your site is doing at the network level. What request/response happens when that RedirectToAction occurs?

Comment: Are you doing any authorization's?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually I can't download Fiddler right now because of IT restrictions in my company. Can you please tell more about this filter and how to disable it?

Comment: @tereško : I will make note of this. Thanks.

Comment: @ssilas777 : No authorization as of now. I have just started with my project.

Comment: Did you get any solution to the above problem. I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Pages such as your Index page on Home Controller will need `[AllowAnonymous]` decorating the action to allow the page to be viewed without logging in.

do this

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

            return View();
        }
```

You will also need

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult LogIn(string email, string password)
{          
   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");           
}
```

Comment: Did this. Still the same Login screen.

Comment: Yes Index function of HomeController is called which I already mentioned in my question.

Comment: You haven't allowed anon users to post to your Login page

Comment: Then the code you have shown doesn't reveal any more hints. Possibly related to the other open question you have where you try to post your LogIn form using JQuery?

Comment: You want any other info on this ?

Comment: For both the Home and Account Controllers, put the `[AllowAnonymous]` at controller level as a test to see if it works. If that fails, then I need more info on what has been changed from the out of the box project to have an idea of the cause.